# When was @interface introduced in java?

Tags: java, annotations

I know this @interface element is used to define annotations in Java.
I know annotations were introduced in Java 5.

My questions:

1) how is that element called (formally), and since when
is it recognized by the compiler i.e. when was it introduced?
Is it an annotation or a meta-annotation itself?

2) before Java 8 (e.g. in Java 5 or 6) was there some other element/way
used for defining annotations or had they always been defined that
way ever since their advent in the language?

Comment: Well, you _declare_ an annotation using `public @interface Whatever`, so it appeared at the same time that annotations appeared

Comment: @fge That's what I'm asking. Maybe in the past something else was used to define annotations? So you mean "no, the `@interface` has always been used for defining annotations"?

Comment: Well, there was no annotations prior to 1.5; and I guess trying and `public @interface Whatever` in 1.4 or less was a compile error... Haven't tried ;)

Comment: @fge No, you didn't understand me. Look, I mean, maybe in Java 5 there was another construct to define annotations.

Comment: I see; well, no, not to my knowledge, at least

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how is that element called (formally), and since when is it recognized by the compiler i.e. when was it introduced?

An [annotation type declaration](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6). This was added in Java 5.

> Is it an annotation or a meta-annotation itself?

No, `@interface` is not an annotation by itself, it's just the keyword `interface` preceded by an `@`. It's not a meta-annotation. A meta-annotation is an annotation that can be used on annotation type declarations. The JDK itself has a number of these (for example `@RetentionPolicy`).

> before Java 8 (e.g. in Java 5 or 6) was there some other element/way used for defining annotations

No.

> or they had they always been defined that way ever since their advent in the language?

Yes.

Annotations have been added in Java 5 and `@interface` was always the way to create annotations; there has not been any other mechanism in the past to create annotations.

Why `@interface` and not a new keyword such as `annotation`: This was done for backward compatibility. Adding a new keyword means you immediately create a backward compatibility issue, because programs written for the older version might have used the name of the keyword for example as a variable name. Such programs wouldn't compile anymore on the new version. So, when they want to add a new feature to Java, Oracle prefers re-using an existing keyword instead of creating a new one.

That said, new keywords have been added in the course of the evolution of Java, such as `enum` and `assert` (which were added in Java 1.4).